# Point of indeterminacy of the projection map (exercise I.4.3 Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove that the morphism $\varphi : W = {\mathbb{P}}^2 \setminus \big\{ [0:0:1] \big\} \rightarrow {\mathbb{P}}^1$ given by $\varphi([a_0 : a_1 : a_2]) = [a_0 : a_1]$ cannot be extended to the point at infinity.

My approach is assuming $\psi : {\mathbb{P}}^2 \rightarrow {\mathbb{P}}^1$ is a morphism such that $\psi \lvert_W = \varphi$ leads to a contradiction. Assuming $\psi([0:0:1]) = [a_0 : a_1] = \psi([a_0 : a_1 : a_2])$, I am trying to cook up a nice regular function which cannot be pulled back to a regular function. Now (w.l.g.) assuming $a_0 \neq 0$, a reasonable choice is $f : U_0 \rightarrow k$ where $U_0 := \big\{ [u_0 : u_1] ~:~ u_0 \neq 0 \big\} \subseteq {\mathbb{P}}^1$.

Taking a small enough open subset $V \subseteq U_0$ where $f = g/h$ (a polynomial quotient), I need to show that $f \circ \psi : \psi^{-1}(V) \rightarrow k$ is not regular. This is where I am lost.

I am not sure if it is the correct way to approach? This is final step to solve exercise I.4.3(b), Hartshorne.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's an easier way to show this. I'll present a hint and then detail how to make it work under some spoiler text so you can try for yourself before looking at the answer.

**Hint**: Consider the two lines $V(x)$ and $V(y)$ in $\Bbb P^2$. What does the projection map do to each of these lines? What can you infer about the possible extensions of this map to the point $[0:0:1]$ via these extensions?

> Projection sends $V(x)\setminus [0:0:1]$ to the point $[0:1]$ and $V(y)\setminus [0:0:1]$ to the point $[1:0]$. Since $V(x)\setminus [0:0:1]$ and $V(y)\setminus [0:0:1]$ are irreducible, we must have that an extension of these maps to $V(x)$ or $V(y)$ respectively must send $[0:0:1]$ into $\overline{\varphi(V(x)\setminus [0:0:1])}$ or $\overline{\varphi(V(y)\setminus [0:0:1])}$ respectively. But this gives that $\varphi([0:0:1])$ should simultaneously be equal to $[0:1]$ and $[1:0]$, a contradiction.

Comment: Nice one. Just a small question: a continuous map $\psi$ satisfy $\psi( {\overline{W}} ) \subseteq {\overline{\psi(W)}}$. Is the "irreducibility" redundant here? Or, I am missing something?

Comment: You're right, that's true. I guess that means irreducibility is redundant, but it was the first thing that came to mind and it's also correct, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯